# PHPKB Extend Session

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have inherited a php knowledge-base cms there was a request that I prolong session so the users will not have to log back in for an extended period of time lets say five days. I found in the login function I could extend the cookie max/lifetime value by adding the following code.

```
setcookie(session_name(),$_COOKIE[session_name()],time()+3600*24*5);
```

I check the cookie in the developer tools and it does extend the lifetime but the users are still being redirected to login after just a few minutes of inactivity. Also using Chromephp extension I find that the session variables are empty when I write the session object to console log upon refreshing the login page.

I'm running on an Ubuntu lamp server I have checked a few options in the php.ini and can't seem to find one that will extend the lifetime of the session. Also another question would be what risk would run into as far as server memory and performance by extending sessions when up to 50 users may be utilizing this kb.  As always thanks in advance any advice is welcome.

Comment: My guess is that there is something else expiring the cookie.. Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to set a cookie with the same name as the session name?  That is not going to be useful at all.  The typical cookie name is `PHPSESSID`.

That being said, just extending the cookie expiration time is not going to actually extend the time that the session data lives on the server.

You need to actually set your session lifetime and session cookie lifetime in your PHP.ini settings.  See this link to the StackOverflow question that covers how to do this.

[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I was under the wrong impression that the session cookie was storing the data needed for the user session but after some more reading php session uses this cookie just to store the session id nothing else.

Comment: @vikingben That is correct PHP will associate the session ID with the session data stored stored in either temp files (in typical default installation) or some other storage medium (database etc.) that you may define using custom session handlers. That is a very important security aspect of sessions, that the session data are not accessible on the client side.